# Adding to Complex nested python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider I have below dictionary.

```
d ={'parent1': {'2': {'3': {}}},'parent2':{'child1':{},'child2':{}}}
```

Every key has value in the dictionary format.

Now I want to add into the key value pair "u" into the above dictionary d.

```
u = {"4":"2"} # dictionary that I want to add as a key to a child.
```

I am trying to add it "child1" of 'parent2':{'child1':{},'child2':{}}` .
u = {"4":"2"} is a value to a key. you can choose any key name.

So that my final result will look like

```
d ={'parent1': {'2': {'3': {}}},'parent2':{'child1':{'newkey':{'4':'2'}}, 'child2':{}}}
```

What we know already is where we have to add the new information(key:value) and that is provided in the form of list.
path = ['parent2','child1']

This path represent the path where we have to add the new key:value pair.
In this case it can be read as, we have to go 'parent2' inside that we have child with name 'child1' and in this child we have to store the add new information in as key:value pair.
NOte: The path is not harcoded it can change any time.
Appreciate if you can provide me solution in python or if you can provide logic. Thanks

Comment: d[path[0]][path[1]]['newkey'] = u

Comment: that's definitely not the answer

Comment: Can you explain the "list.path" section again?? I've got an answer but I'm confused by this part

Comment: sorry, that was not "list. path". here "." means the end of the statement. I have updated my question hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Given the way you have explained this problem... @itproh66 has given you the right answer to do what you have asked.

Comment: what should we do when we have to add the same thing in 1000 nodes do we write the boxes 1000 times!! That will be mess I think then

Answer (score 0):

I beg your pardon, but given the following:

```
d ={'parent1': {'2': {'3': {}}},'parent2':{'child1':{},'child2':{}}}
u = {"4":"2"} # dictionary that I want to add as a key to a child.
path = ['parent2','child1']
```

Then the command

```
d[path[0]][path[1]]['newkey'] = u
```

Yields:

```
{'parent1': {'2': {'3': {}}},
 'parent2': {'child1': {'newkey': {'4': '2'}}, 'child2': {}}}
```

Which is exactly what you asked for.
Please explain why this is not the right answer

Comment: This is one way but not a smart way. Say as an example we have to make changes in below dictionary ` d ={'parent1': {'2': {'3': {}}},'parent2':{'child1':{},'child2':{}},'parent3':{'child1':{},'child2':{}},'parent4':{'child1':{},'child2':{}},'parent5':{'child1':{},'child2':{}},'parent6':{'child1':{},'child2':{'parent4':{'child1':{'parent4':{'child1':{},'child2':{}}},'child2':{}}}}}` <br/> now if I want to add the dict at `path=['parent6','child2','parent4','child2']`.  <br/> if we write `d[path[0]][path[1][path[2]][path[3]]]['newkey']` ..keep on increasing when path move in deep.

Comment: And if your path keeps on changing how will you manage then, because you have already hardcoded this. `d[path[0]][path[1][path[2]][path[3]]]['newkey']`

Comment: Since the idea of the path changing wasn't included in your problem description, it wasn't included in my answer. Be careful what you ask for, you are likely to get it.